# How to implement delayed retry mechanism in a Kafka streaming (kstreams) application built in spring cloud stream?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, reactive-programming, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have a scenarios like.

There are 4 topics  **Processing topic , exception topic , Retry Topic and reject topic**.
I have spring cloud stream application that has a processor which use a Kstream. This processor reads message from exception topic and based on a flag available in each message
creates two kstream branches for retry Topic and Reject topic.
Now what needs to be done is any message that is present in retry topic has to wait for a specific period of time before pushing it back to Processing topic.
can anyone help me what is the best design or solution to do it in a kafka stream application in spring cloud stream.
Can it be designed with asynchronous mechanism using flux and Mono. any resource or guidance would be a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

we cannot mix reactive types in a Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams application. Basically, you can only have Kafka Streams types such as `KStream` or `KTable` as input/output bindings. If you want to introduce a delay before sending it out to the processing topic, why can't you use something like a `ScheduleExecutorService` and then only call the service after the initial delay? Here is a sample pseudo code for a potential solution.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
...
...

.branch(
   (k, v) -> {
     if (reject flag found) {
       return true;
     }
   }
   (k, v) -> executorService.schedule(() -> true, initialDelay, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

In the first branch, we check to see if the record is bound for rejected status, if so, send it immediately to the rejected topic. Otherwise, it is targeted for the retry topic, delay with some value (I guess this is configured externally in your application) before returning the boolean flag. Upon completion of the delay, the boolean `true` will return and the record that came to the branch will be sent to the retry topic.

Please keep in mind that I haven't tried this code, so beware of any race conditions in that second filter where we hand off things to the scheduler in an async manner, but that thread context should still retain the current `(k,v)` pair. Please try this with some test data to see if it meets your requirements.